# Create sprites in class and get collision

Tags: python, pygame

Hi i'm learning python by creating a game. I use pygame to create the game where two players fight in knight tournment. The idea of ​​game is simple, from two sides players need to press gallop key and operating the spear to hit eachother. I have class with move of the block and i want to add the spear inside the class but i can't draw spear ...

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

#Class

class Knight(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x, pos_y, width, height, color):
        super().__init__()

        #Knight image
        self.image= pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = [pos_x, pos_y]

        #Knight spear
        self.image_spear = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
        self.image_spear.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect_spear = self.image_spear.get_rect(center=(pos_x, pos_y))
        self.angle_spear = 0
    def player_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        #Moving knight
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.move = 1
            self.rect.x +=self.move
        #Moving spear
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.angle_spear += 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.angle_spear -= 1

    def update(self):
        #Update moving knight
        self.player_input()
        #Update spear
        self.angle_spear = self.angle_spear
        self.image_spear.fill(0)
        pygame.draw.line(self.image_spear, (255, 255, 100), (self.pos_x, 30+self.pos_y), (100 + self.pos_x, self.poy+self.angle), 5)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image= pygame.Surface([800, 100])
        self.image.fill('white')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = [0, 400]



#screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Geometry_War")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#screen view
#ground = pygame.Rect(0, 300, 800, 200)
#ground_screen=pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', ground)

#start values
game_active = True
Knight1 = Knight(100, 300, 60, 60,(255,125,125))
Knight2 = Knight(700, 300, 60, 60,(255,000,125))
Ground = Ground()
#Sprite group
sprite_group=pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite_group.add(Knight1, Knight2,Ground)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

    if game_active:

        screen.fill(0)
        sprite_group.update()
        sprite_group.draw(screen)



    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The idea:
[image]

In next step i want to get point of collision and calculate the power of hit for each player(fast*point =score). Better score wins. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How have you tried debugging this? I immediately get an error because `Knight` does not have a `pos_x` member. In addition, you have tried to use `self.poy` instead of `self.pos_y`.

Comment: @LayneBernardo yes this is my fault ... sory. This is one of the problems but when i change "pos" to numbers nothing is change ... (still nothing is drawing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.  There's a few typos in the code (as commented by Layne Bernardo) that are causing the immediate issues. Fix them, and it will start to work.

[image: animation]

One other issue is the handling of user-input inside the `Knight` sprite class.  I think doing this here is a mistake.  The sprite class exists to hold the position and dimensions of an on-screen bitmap, not process user input.  This should be moved outside of the class, probably to the main loop.  If you still want it separate, put it inside a function, but not a sprite member-function.

Below I fixed up the code to the point where it would work, then got carried away playing with lance-angles... eventually re-working a lot of the Knight class.

```
import pygame
import math
from sys import exit

#Class

class Knight(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x, pos_y, width, height, color):
        super().__init__()
        #Knight image
        self.image= pygame.Surface([width*2, height*2])   # note: twice width to leave room for rotating spear
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = ( pos_x, pos_y )
        self.base_color  = color
        #Knight spear
        self.spear_color  = ( 255, 255, 100 )
        self.spear_length = 50  # pixels
        self.spear_angle  = 180
        self.makeSpriteImage()  # get initial rendering
        # Movement
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 1  # 1=right, -1=left

    def update( self ):
        """ Move the horsey ... if we have any speed """
        self.rect.x += self.speed * self.direction

    def makeSpriteImage( self ):
        """ Draw the Knight's representation into the sprite image.
            Done whenever the image needs to change """
        self.image.fill( ( 0, 0, 0, 0, ) ) # transparent
        pygame.draw.rect( self.image, self.base_color, pygame.Rect( 0,self.rect.height//2, self.rect.width//2, self.rect.height//2 ) );  # quarter-fill bottom-left corner
        spear_base_x  = self.rect.width  // 4  # width is double
        spear_base_y  = self.rect.width // 2 + self.rect.height // 4
        spear_point_x = spear_base_x + ( self.spear_length * math.sin( math.radians( self.spear_angle ) ) ) 
        spear_point_y = spear_base_y + ( self.spear_length * math.cos( math.radians( self.spear_angle ) ) )
        pygame.draw.line( self.image, self.spear_color, (spear_base_x, spear_base_y), (spear_point_x, spear_point_y), 2 )
        #print( "Line at %d degrees, from (%d,%d) to (%d,%d) length %d" % ( self.spear_angle, spear_base_x, spear_base_y, spear_point_x, spear_point_y, self.spear_length ) )
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    # Handle user-change to the sprite
    def accelerate( self, amount=2 ):
        self.speed += amount
    def decelerate( self, amount=2 ):
        self.speed += amount
    def turnAround( self ):
        self.direction = -self.direction  # flip directions

    def setSpearPosition( self, angle ):
        """ The user has adjusted the spear position, regenerate the Knight's image """
        self.spear_angle = angle
        self.spear_angle = max( 45, self.spear_angle )  # Keep spear angle sensible
        self.spear_angle = min( 180, self.spear_angle )
        self.makeSpriteImage()  # regenerate the bitmap

    def raiseSpear( self ):
        self.setSpearPosition( self.spear_angle + 3 )
    def lowerSpear( self ):
        self.setSpearPosition( self.spear_angle - 3 )


class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image= pygame.Surface([800, 100])
        self.image.fill('white')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = [0, 400]



#screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Geometry_War")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#start values
game_active = True
Knight1 = Knight(100, 300, 60, 60,(255,125,125))
Knight2 = Knight(700, 300, 60, 60,(255,000,125))
Ground = Ground()
# Sprite group
background_group=pygame.sprite.Group()  # background group does not need to update
background_group.add(Ground)
knight_group=pygame.sprite.Group()
knight_group.add(Knight1, Knight2)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    # handle player input
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Moving knight
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        Knight1.accelerate()
    if keys[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        Knight1.decelerate()   # wooooah!

    #Moving spear
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        Knight1.raiseSpear()
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        Knight1.lowerSpear()

    # Paint the screen
    screen.fill(0)
    knight_group.update()
    knight_group.draw(screen)
    background_group.draw(screen)

    #pygame.display.flip()   # flip() or update(), not both
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I put inputs in class beacause many yt teachers did that in pygame tutorial. Your definition is more clear.

Comment: Heh ... you can't believe everything you watch on TV  ;)